# Mount achive as a virtual drive

Tags: windows, virtualization, archiving, device-driver

I want to mount achive (preferably 7z, but any nice one is ok) as a virtual drive in Windows.

There are following facts:

1. Let's assume that we have an empty achive. When it'll be created doesn't matter.
2. This archive should be mounted as a drive.
3. The only file will be written to that drive.
4. Compression should take place *during* writing.
5. Writing will be sequential (but NOT realtime).
6. Expected size of uncompressed data varies from 100 GB to 500 GB.
7. Expected size of achive is 500 times smaller than original data.
8. There is NO enough place to fit uncompressed file anywhere.
9. It would be nice to have ability of sequential reading after the writing is finished.

The recorded data is uncompressed avi. Windows is requred.

**What programs can I use to make it possible?**

By the way 7zip can achive stream. For example following command packs output of `cmd /?` into `cmd.7z` as `help.txt` (ключ `-si`):

```
cmd /? | "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -sihelp.txt cmd.7z
```

So any program that can create virtual drive, and pass content written to a single file there to `stdout` can be used to archive the goal.

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/616781/178988)

Comment: Can you write to a network share? On that share - a *nix machine - you have a fifo, and a process that basically does `cat fifofile | gzip > bigcompressedfile.gz`.  You could do the same with `bzip2`.  But a 500x compression and able to get an uncompressed avi out of it?  Don't think it will happen...

Comment: @ivanivan, seems like no.